# Android Retrofit request JDWP 103 Error

Tags: java, android, python-requests, retrofit, dagger

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET(DownworkApi.BASE_URL + DownworkApi.EXTENSION_URL + "person/getbyusername/{username}")
    Call<JsonObject> getPersonByUsername(
        @Path("username") String username);

    @GET(DownworkApi.BASE_URL + DownworkApi.EXTENSION_URL + "person/getall")
    Call<JsonObject> getAllUsers();
```

These requests are in an interface, which is in a class. Each time I am going with the debugger, I get and "Unexpected JDWP 103 Error".

I get the class (instantiated) and then api.getService().REQUEST. Service is the interface mentioned earlier.

I am also using dagger2 for dependency injection to instantiate the api class, but when debugging everything seems fine on that part. When it comes to the api class and service, everything seems just fine.

```
Response<JsonObject> response = downworkApi.getDownworkApiService().getAllUsers().execute();
```

I am also using the JsonObject class from `com.google.gson` package. I am not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this problem ? I am facing it right now and have no idea what to do.